# Using Multiple Databases within a controller asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two separate VS Solutions both work fine accessing the databases associated with them.

How ever I need to look up some details from the other database to be displayed in the other solution.

Ive added the second connection string to the web.config and then added the context to my DAL:

```
namespace RACentral.DAL
{
public class RACentralContext : DbContext
{

    public RACentralContext()
        : base("RACDev")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<RiskAssessment> RiskAssessments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hazard> Hazards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PPE> PPEs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RiskAssessmentPPE> RiskAssessmentPPEs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PeopleExposed> PeopleExposeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RiskAssessmentPeopleExposed> RiskAssessmentPeopleExposeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RiskAssessmentHazard> RiskAssessmentHazards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ControlMeasure> ControlMeasures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Severity> Severitys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Likelihood> Likelihoods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AddControlMeasure> AddControlMeasures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubType> SubTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

public class PeopleContext : DbContext
{

    public PeopleContext()
        : base("PeopleContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
}
```

I get an error in the controller

> 'Not set to an instance of an object,'

Am trying to access it in my controller as follow:

```
public class RiskAssessmentController : Controller
{
    private RACentralContext db = new RACentralContext();
    private PeopleContext Peopledb = new PeopleContext();

    public ViewResult StartRA()
    {
        var user = User.Identity.Name;
        string userName = user.Substring(7);
        var test = Peopled.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == 1) //Error here


        StartRiskAssessmentViewModel viewModel = new StartRiskAssessmentViewModel
        {
            RiskAssessment = new RiskAssessment(),
            Assessor = userName,

        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ??

Comment: I cat get that far as I can't select a table in the Peopledb

Comment: You arent selecting a table youre trying to select an entity. You have no entites in the data context. Trying adding some...

Comment: Edited @heymega to show the error I get when adding an entity

Comment: I hoping that you're missing a reference to your Person class and not just hoping it would automagically map to your person table...You actually need to have a class called person which defines your mapping to your table in the DB. If you're just starting to use EF then check out http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net

Comment: I did have a class for Person but I got an error when trying to reference a Person that it wasn't set to an instance of an object, I suspect that I'm not doing the mapping correctly in the class, should the class just be a copy of the class from the other solution or mapped in some way?

Comment: Ideally your data layer is separated out into it's own project then you could just include the dll from the other solution instead of duplicating the code

Comment: Even duplicating the code isn't working